# Excel VBA Workbook_SheetChange does not work with all inputs

Tags: excel, vba

`If Target <> "" Then`

A specific line of code makes an error here.

> Error announcement is **Type Mismatch**.

I have a certain are in a sheet where user can write or paste numeric values without changing number formatting or cells formatting. I would like to enable all methods to input data into sheet. How I should fix the code?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

        On Error GoTo Err_Something

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Application.Undo

        If Target <> "" Then
               ' user just type value in the excel sheet
           Else
                ' user pastes data from other unknown excel sources
                  Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
       End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        Exit Sub

Err_Something:

    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

> FINAL SOLUTION

I tested many different variant how to fire these events, but I never found reliable solution. Therefore I made a separate Sub, which runs every-time when user launch the program.

```
Sub visualMethod()

    With ws
        .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(22, 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(22, 10)).Font.Name = "Courier New"
        .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(22, 10)).Font.Size = 12
        .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(22, 10)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(22, 10)).Borders.Weight = xlThin
        .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(22, 10)).NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your Target is the worksheet object. Why are you comparing it to an empty string? If you want to check if the object is Nothing, I think that's pointless as it cannot be Nothing since it triggers the event.

Comment: Because I am looking here code what works and I haven't found that yet. Did you got idea of my code?

Comment: @jivko  `Target` is a range object whose default value is `Target.Value`. `Target <> ""` evaluates to `Target.Value <> ""`.  Although this is not a best practice it is acceptable.  I don't see where the user is wanting to check if `Target is Nothing`?

Comment: It seems that you want to ensure that the formats stay intact.  Formatting does not trigger any events.  For this reason, I recommend protecting your formats by password protecting your worksheets.

Comment: That is also a topic that I have googled without success. How to protect sheet that only pasting values in certain ranges is possible excluding cell formating.

Comment: @Thomas Inzina I misinterpreted the event name. I thought it referred to changing the active sheet. `Target <> ""` throws an error when Target contains multiple cells.